# Set img src from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am working on a standard web form in asp.net and I have two items in my images folder:

`images/Clear_Flag.png`
`images/S_Flag.png`

I have been able to set the background color of these items dynamically from a SQL database, but I cannot set the file location - I've tried lots of different syntax, but I'm getting the red cross error.

Sample code below:

In Code:

```
<img src=<#% Eval("Flag_Location") %;'> style='background-color: <%# Eval("Flag_Color") %>;'/>
```

Fields returned from query

`Flag_Colour`: Blue

`Flag_Location`: ~/images/Clear_Flag.png

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: provide the full snippet of the *.aspx code ...

Comment: `<img src='<#% Eval("Flag_Location") %>'` - correct that

Comment: What does that element look like when you do a view source on the rendered output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @codingbiz - I didn't notice the semi colon at the end of the line, that also helped to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag location should be

```
/images/Clear_Flag.png
```

Either remove the "~" in your DB or strip the "~" from the image src.

Comment: Thanks MikeSmithDev, a combination of the unnecessary ~ plus the semi colon turned out to be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Leave the Flag_Location as is and add a runat="server" attribute. This way it should resolve correctly, even if the directory structure is later changed.